# Use a Azure AD Bearer Token to access O365 Exchange REST APIs (mail, contacts, etc)

Tags: ruby, ms-office, office365, azure-active-directory

I am using Azure AD to provision and license new users in O365 and it works beautifully, however I need some further O365 functionality (i.e. being able to export a user's contacts). I noticed that there are permissions for your app to do this:

[image]

I get can a bearer token to do all my other REST calls similar to this code (in ruby using httparty):

```
domain = "example.com"
api_version = "1.5"
auth_url = "https://login.windows.net/#{domain}/oauth2/token?api-version=#{api_version}"
auth_body = {"grant_type" => "client_credentials", "client_id" => @client_id, "client_secret" => @client_secret}
auth_headers = {"Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
token_resp = HTTParty.post(auth_url, :headers => auth_headers, :body => auth_body)
bearer_token = "Bearer #{token_resp['access_token']}"
```

It works great on calls to https://graph.windows.net/ however when I try to make calls on O365 Exchange:

```
request_headers={"Authorization" => bearer_token, "Content-Type"=>"application/json"}
request = HTTParty.get("https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/users/user@example.com", :headers => request_headers)
```

or

```
request = HTTParty.get("https://api.office.com/discovery/v1.0/me/services", :headers => request_headers)
```

I get the following response:

> HTTParty::Response:0x7fea2f8b0e40 parsed_response={"error"=>{"code"=>"-2147024891,
>   System.UnauthorizedAccessException", "message"=>"Access denied. You do
>   not have permission to perform this action or access this
>   resource."}}, @response=#, @headers={"cache-control"=>["private, max-age=0"],
>   "transfer-encoding"=>["chunked"],
>   "content-type"=>["application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false;charset=utf-8"], "expires"=>["Mon, 29 Dec 2014 19:27:04 GMT"], "last-modified"=>["Tue,
>   13 Jan 2015 19:27:04 GMT"], "server"=>["Microsoft-IIS/8.0"],
>   "x-correlationid"=>["595d3bd9-94f7-40fe-b4ed-c3a28cc74cdb"],
>   "x-usersessionid"=>["595d3bd9-94f7-40fe-b4ed-c3a28cc74cdb"],
>   "x-officefe"=>["OdcFrontEnd_IN_10"],
>   "x-officeversion"=>["16.0.3705.3001"],
>   "x-officecluster"=>["scus-odc.officeapps.live.com"], "p3p"=>["CP=\"CAO
>   DSP COR ADMa DEV CONi TELi CUR PSA PSD TAI IVDi OUR SAMi BUS DEM NAV
>   STA UNI COM INT PHY ONL FIN PUR\""], "odata-version"=>["4.0"],
>   "x-aspnet-version"=>["4.0.30319"], "x-powered-by"=>["ASP.NET"],
>   "date"=>["Tue, 13 Jan 2015 19:27:03 GMT"], "connection"=>["close"]}>

Am I missing something here? How can I use a bearer token for my app to access the Exchange Online APIs? Is there any docs for this? I can't seem to find anything on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

"have full access to a user's mailbox" requires administrative access. I would suggest turning that permission off and giving it another go.

Comment: In general I think that all the "full access *" permissions might require admin permissions. Anyway, I am going to flag this thread for my O365 friends to see if they can take a look. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible I may need authenticate with some sort of account that has full access to the account I want to pull info for? I am trying to use the application token but I'm starting to think it will only take a user token

Comment: The application token won't work, the permissions you are setting there are delegated

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the user themselves needs to sign in and grant your app access to the Contacts API. We are working on releasing app-only permissions (similar to what Graph has now) shortly.

Comment: Makes sense. Could I use like an impersonation account that has full access to the accounts I want to get info for?

Comment: Not yet. Once app-only is in play, you don't need an account at all :)

Comment: What's the ETA for that?

Comment: "Very soon". Sorry I can't be more concrete. If you want to know as soon as possible, follow me on Twitter (@JasonJohMSFT) or watch our blog's RSS feed (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/).

Comment: Instead of implement something heavy and complex under the hood, can be this an "Administrative consents wizard" or "administrative sign-up wizard"? When admin picks list of users or selects option "all users", an application, and consent action (allow/revoke), and the wizard adds/removes the records from consent db (users lists of apps actually). BTW, these records can be marked with a flag "byOrganization" or such to prevent modification of this record by user and make user aware why this app is "installed" for him/her?... Can this be implemented in this way?

Comment: I can pass the suggestion along.

Comment: @JasonJohnston I'm assuming this is the answer to this now? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2015/01/22/building-demon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow.aspx

Comment: Yes. That is the option to grant an app permission to all users in the organization.